# If $f(t)\geq0$ and $\dot{f}(t)=g(t)+h(t)$ with $g(t)\leq0$ and $\lim_{t\to+\infty}h(t)=0$, can we prove that $\lim_{t\to+\infty}\dot{f}(t)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

I have the following question: If $f(t)\geq0$ and $\dot{f}(t)=g(t)+h(t)$ with $g(t)\leq0$ and $\lim_{t\to+\infty}h(t)=0$, can we prove that $\lim_{t\to+\infty}\dot{f}(t)=0$? Note that both $g(t)$ and $h(t)$ are continuous functions. This question is related to an engineering problem in the field of sensor networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.

We set $h(t) \equiv 0$ so that $h(t)\to 0$ trivially.

1. For $g$, put $g(t)=0$ for $t<1$, on each interval $[n,n+1)$, $n\ge 1$, we make $g(t) = -1$ for a time $2^{-n}$, and $0$ otherwise. For example
   $$
   g(t) = \begin{cases}  -1 & t\in[1,1+1/2) \\ 0 & t\in [1+1/2,2)\\-1 & t\in[2,2+1/4)\\
   0 & t\in [2+1/4,3)\\ -1& t\in [3, 3+1/8)\\ 0 & t\in[3+1/8,4)\\ \vdots & \vdots \qquad \vdots \end{cases}
   $$
   Clearly then, $f'=g$ has no limit, and if we make $f(0)$ large enough, say $f(0) = 100$, then $f\ge 0$ for all time. In fact, the integral of $g$ over all times is precisely $\sum_{n=1}^\infty - 2^{-n}= -1$, so $f(0)=1$ is enough.
2. With more work, a continuously differentiable example is possible. Let $\phi(x)$ be your favourite smooth function compactly supported on $[0,1]$ with $\phi(1/2) = 2$ and $\int_0^1 \phi dx = 1$. Define
   $$\phi_n(x) = \phi(2^n(x-n))$$
   Then $\phi_n$ is compactly supported on $[n, n+2^{-n}]$, with integral  $\int_n^{n+1} \phi_n dx = 2^{-n}$. Now define $g_1(t) = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \phi_n(t) $, i.e.
   $$
   g(t) = \begin{cases}  -\phi_1(t) & t\in[1,2) \\
   -\phi_2(t) & t\in[2,3)\\
   -\phi_3(t) & t\in[3,4) \\ \vdots & \vdots \qquad \vdots \end{cases}
   $$
   Then $f'=g \in C^\infty$, $g\le 0$, and $\int_0^\infty g dx = -1.$ So  if we choose $f(0)=1$, then $f\ge 0$. As $g(n+2^{-n-1}) = -2$ and $g(n)=0$ for all $n$, $f'$ has no limit.
3. In the comments, the OP asked (I'm paraphrasing) if enforcing $g<0$ can prevent the counterexample. The answer is still no. Just choose $f'(t)=g(t)= -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \phi_n(t) - e^{-t} $. Now $g<0$, and $\int_0^\infty g dx = -2  $. So now if we choose $f(0)=2$, then $f> 0$ for all $t$, and this is still a counterexample. (And if we choose $f(0)>2$ then $\lim_{t\to\infty} f(t)>0$ also.)
    
   [Desmos has trouble](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/52vuawk555) plotting such an example, but this approximate plot for $t<5$ may give you some intuition.[image]Green ($\color{green}\blacksquare$) is $\phi$, blue ($\color{blue}\blacksquare$) is $g=f'$, and purple ($\color{purple}\blacksquare$) is $f$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. What if Lebesgue measure of the set $\{t\geq0| g(t)=0\}$ is zero?

Comment: @CUG that is not an issue. Instead of switching $-1,0,-1,0,-1,...$ you can change the sequences of 0s into a sequence of strictly negative numbers that converge to 0 very quickly, without changing the qualitative behavior. And you can of course still make $g$ continuous or smooth with this change. If I have time tomorrow and no one else has done so, I will see if I can spell this out explicitly

Comment: Kho Thanks. If we construct a sequence of strictly negative numbers that converge to 0 very quickly, does this imply that $\lim_{t\to+\infty}\dot{f}(t)=0$? It confirms the statement of my question, right?

Comment: If we construct a sequence of strictly negative numbers that converge to 0 very quickly (i.e. $\lim_{t\to+\infty}g(t)=0$), does this imply that $\lim_{t\to+\infty}\dot{f}(t)=0$?@Calvin Kho

Comment: @CUG, no, because I didnt touch the sequence of -1s, in that construction.

Comment: @CUG I've updated the example

Comment: Thanks. I see and $\dot{f}(t)$ should be uniformly continuous or $\ddot{f}(t)$ is bounded to ensure $\lim_{t\to\infty}\dot{f}(t)=0$ (i.e., Barbalat's lemma).

Comment: @CUG you're welcome; thanks for telling me about Barbalat's lemma which I didn't know about. If my answer has been useful you can upvote it and/or accept it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138756/discussion-between-cug-and-calvin-khor).

Answer (score 0):

**No.** Define $h(t)=1$ for $t \in [1,2)$, $h(t)=\frac{1}{2}$ for $t \in [2, 4)$ and so on $h(t)=2^{-k}$ for $t \in [2^k, 2^{k+1})$. Note that the integral of $h$ for each interval $[2^k, 2^{k+1})$ is equal to $1$. Now let $g(t)=-1$ if $t \in [2^k, 2^k+1)$ for some positive integer $k$ and $g(t)=0$ otherwise, then the integral of $g$ for each interval $[2^k, 2^{k+1})$ is equal to $-1$. Hence th two cancel out of each such interval and if we set $f(0)=1$ then $f(t) \in [0,2]$ for all $t$.

With some more effort one can construct continous or even smooth examples of $g, h$ with the same basic idea.

Comment: @quarague Thanks. please note that $g(t)\leq0$.

Comment: @CUG True, sign error on my part, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

To add to one of the answers above: no. This answer is similar, but is continuous (hence avoides the non-differentiability problem).

Again, let $h(x) = 0$, so it converges to 0.

Now let $g(x) = \frac{-1}{2^x}$. We can find options for $f(x)$ simply by integrating $g(x)$.

$$f(x) = f(0) + \int_{0}^{x}g(y)dy = f(0) + \int_{0}^{x}\frac{-1}{2^y}dy = f(0) + \frac{2^{-x} - 1}{\log 2} \to f(0) - \frac{1}{\log 2}$$

So if we say that $f(0) = 1 + \frac{1}{\log 2}$ we have our counter example:

1. $f(x) = 1 + \frac{2^{-x}}{\log 2} > 0$.
2. $g(x) = \frac{1}{2^x} < 0$.
3. $h(x) = 0 \to 0$.
4. $f'(x) = g(x) + h(x)$
5. $f(x) \to f(0) - \frac{1}{\log{2}} = 1 \neq 0$.

And $f(x)$ is infinitely continuously derivable (in case that's a requirement).

EDIT: whoops I switched $t$ for $x$. Doesn't change the counter example though.

Comment: Thanks. but I think you example confirms the claim in my posted question, instead of providing a counterexample.

Comment: Oh my apologies. I now see you were talking about $f'(t)$ instead of $f(t)$. Whoops.